# Custom field not displayed on user page layout

Tags: page-layout

I am adding a custom field to the user page layout, with the admin rights, but the field is not showing nor my section. Doest anyone know why ?

Comment: Check too see if the fields is visible for the user. If you add fields to a section and you don't have visibility on all the fields, the whole section won't appear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check too see if the fields is visible for the user. 
Also, If you add fields to a section and you don't have visibility on all the fields, the whole section won't appear.

Comment: Yes, this is it :)